# Improve query speed for large, wide table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, table

I have created a medical claims database using PostgreSQL 9.4.1 and pgAdmin III. There is one table with ~61 million rows and 103 columns. The table has the structure given below. It is static and will not be updated. (Most columns are omitted here to save space.)

```
    CREATE TABLE claims
   (
     spending double precision,
     releaseid bigint NOT NULL,
     priceinclude bytea,
     costsharing double precision,
     hcciprofode bytea,
     memberlinkeid bigint,
     age integer,
     orgid integer,
     gender character(1),
     membercity character varying(22),
     memberstate character(2),
     zip character varying(5),
     principaldiagnosis character varying(6),
     CONSTRAINT claims_pkid PRIMARY KEY (releaseid)
   )
   WITH (
     OIDS=FALSE
   );

Indexes:
"claims_pkid" PRIMARY KEY, btree (releaseid)
"claims_age_idx" btree (age)
"claims_memberlinkeid_idx" btree (memberlinkeid)
"claims_principaldiagnosis_idx" btree (principaldiagnosis)
"claims_serviceprovider_idx" btree (serviceprovider)
"claims_zip_idx" btree (zip)
```

The indexes shown above are the only ones I've added so far. I am running the database using Windows 7 with the following hardware:

- 64-bit Windows 7
- 32.0 GB RAM
- Intel Core i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40 GHz

My main question involves what I can do to improve query speed without buying a dedicated server. I am trying to demonstrate a proof-of-concept to my supervisors to show them that SQL would be faster than the statistical package the currently use, STATA. I have optimized the default settings of PostgreSQL as follows:

```
shared_buffers=8GB
effective_cache_size=24GB
work_mem=1GB
maintenance_work_mem=1GB
checkpoint_segments=128
checkpoint_completion=0.9
wal_buffers=-1
default_stat_target=500
```

However, the queries are still slow. For example, the following query

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE
SELECT * FROM claims
WHERE gender='F'
AND age BETWEEN 16 AND 20
LIMIT 100000;
```

returns this:

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..226622.43 rows=100000 width=427) (actual time=0.029..9509.028 rows=100000 loops=1)
Output: spending, releaseid, priceinclude, costsharing, hcciprofcode, htype, 
hcciotpcode, drgmpr, medsurg, typecode, claimcat, memberlinkeid, age, orgid, 
insurancetype, gender, membercity, memberstate, zip, admissiondate, serviceprovider, 
servicenpi, ser (...)"
->  Seq Scan on public.claims  (cost=0.00..4778859.76 rows=2108732 width=427) 
(actual time=0.028..9497.420 rows=100000 loops=1)"
Output: spending, releaseid, priceinclude, costsharing, 
hcciprofcode, htype, hcciotpcode, drgmpr, medsurg, 
typecode, claimcat, memberlinkeid, age, orgid, 
insurancetype, gender, membercity, memberstate, 
zip, admissiondate, serviceprovider, servicenp (...)"
Filter: ((claims.age >= 16) AND (claims.age <= 20) AND (claims.gender = 'F'::bpchar))"
"Rows Removed by Filter: 3194024"
"Planning time: 0.190 ms"
"Execution time: 9519.455 ms"
```

Should I be creating a new view or a smaller table to access frequently used columns? I have never created a database this large so I am quite perplexed as to what to do!

**UPDATE:** My goal is to be able to query this database in a reasonable amount of time for exploratory data analysis. 15 seconds for queries is reasonable; 5 minutes for queries on the whole table is not. I am not sure how best to deal with this large table in order to achieve that goal, which is what I would like help with. (Apologies if this is a little vague.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the query in question and the execution plan generated through `explain (analyze, verbose)`. Apart from that: `shared_buffers` should be something like `8GB`, `work_mem` and `maintenance_work_mem` should be much lower. And `wal_buffers` should be set to -1 to let Postgres choose the correct size. Unrelated, but: you should _really_ avoid quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble then they are worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've edited the question to include the output from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and the changes to the server configuration. Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Your `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` shows a sequential scan.  If the index you have mentioned in your question is the ONLY index, then the query you have given us is not able to use that index.  Also, it's not clear if the index you mention is only one index, or actually 4 different one-column indexes.

Comment: Can you show us the index on the Age column please? Also, 9 seconds to select 100,000 rows without an index is pretty fast.

Comment: I've updated the explanation. There are 4 different one-column indexes.

Comment: Try to `ANALYZE` the table. The row estimation in the sequential scan is way off.

Comment: @dezso Worth a shot, but it looks ok to me?  It says it had to scan 3294024 rows before it had 100k rows to return.  3.2m rows is 1/20th of the table .. assuming even distribution of data, 100k is also about 1/20th of the estimated 2108732 rows. (Unless I misunderstand/misread the results?..)

Comment: This query would benefit from an index in gender column.

Comment: @Alexandros I seriously doubt that.

Answer (score -3):

For your example query:
         SELECT * FROM claims
         WHERE gender='F'
         AND age BETWEEN 16 AND 20
         LIMIT 100000;
try to add index on age.
But I suggest to use "SQL SERVER PROFILER" and "Database Engine Tuning Adviser" to monitor your queries, and then add suitable indexes, and make suitable changes.

Comment: Did you realize this question was about PostgreSQL?  Also that there is already an index on `age`?